# How to use SQL LEFT JOIN in my Codeigniter Model

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I make the query with LEFT JOIN in my Codeigniter Model. When i add LEFT JOIN, my web page isn't working and it tell like below

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Here is my query. I Added LEFT JOIN (Not Working Stage). What did i wrong? Please guide me. I'm noob.

```
$sql = "
        SELECT eu.user_id as user_id, DATE_FORMAT(eu.interview_plan_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as plan_date, DATE_FORMAT(eu.interview_plan_date, '%H:%i:%s') as start_time, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(eu.interview_plan_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s') as end_time, count(1) AS cnt  
        FROM `entry_user_tbl` eu
        LEFT JOIN m_admin ma
        ON ma.admin_id = eu.interview_plan_staff
        WHERE delete_flg = 0 
        AND interview_plan_date LIKE '$year-$month%'
        AND CASE 
                WHEN (SELECT admin_flg FROM m_admin WHERE admin_id = {$login_id} AND delete_flg=0) = 0 THEN eu.interview_plan_staff = {$login_id} 
                WHEN {$id} <> 0 THEN eu.interview_plan_staff = {$id}
                ELSE TRUE 
            END
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(interview_plan_date, '%Y%m%d')
        ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a database error you might first turn on your display error, in Codeigniter you can do it by editing index.php page with changing environment to development

```
 define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```